# Including gender diversity in a survey

Tags: political-correctness

I'm about to run a very large survey of Canadians, and I'm wondering how I should identify gender. Currently, I'm asking:

```
Are you ...?

() Male
() Female
```

What word would you use to capture people that don't necessarily fit into either gender? Do I need to?

In person I would refer to a person as the gender they present (for example, in reference to a male that presents themselves as female I would say, "she/her/self") - but I'm not sure how to classify them for the purpose of my survey

Typical survey conventions would suggest "Other", or "None of the above" however, I'm not sure if that would be appropriate nor politically correct. Changing the question type to select all that apply felt like a reasonable option too.

Comment: Downvotes without a comment? Bad form.

Comment: Two fold. To track sampling similarity to Canadian populace and to identify differences based on gender.

Comment: Does it make sense for your survey to actually include the various options of "other"? If you really want to identify differences based on gender it might be useful to know if someone considers them self to be trans or andro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about English but about current gender expectations (would be the same in French as English).

Answer (score 1):

I would say to ask "Are you...
[] male [] female, with a checkbox next to both. That way, people can choose any combination of either, both or neither that they prefer. One problem I see with presenting an "other" option is that you'll get people choosing it just because it is listed as an option. I wouldn't get into distinctions between "gender" and "sex."

Answer (score 1):

I think you're opening a can of worms. This has become a very difficult line of questioning and I have no doubt you're going to cause offense somewhere.

I'd ask in the following way, with the following two questions.

Asking after identity:

> With which gender do you **most** identify, regardless of sex at birth?
>   [] Male
>   [] Female
>   [] Neither
>   [] Both

Asking after biology:

> What sex were you assigned at birth, regardless of how you identify?
>   [] Male
>   [] Female
>   [] Intersex
>   [] Intersex to Male
>   [] Intersex to Female

[Definition of intersex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex), for those who'd like to know.

Comment: You  might consider adding "assigned" ... "sex assigned at birth".

Comment: @Catija, I agree. I'm editing my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been a nightmare ever since we started saying "gender" (which is a broad-spectrum social construct) when we mean "sex" (which is a narrow biological fact).

So why not just say:

```
Sex:
M ()
F ()
Other ()
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I wonder if, for my results, gender is more important than sex.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen "not applicable?"  I see it as one of two or none...  If you are most interested in seeing if people are adamantly ungendered, that seems safe.  Allowing no selection means people can skip the question, but that means plenty of false positives if n/a is an important classification.